# Div background doesn't show (CSS)

Tags: css, background-image

Pretty common problem, judging from what i've been seeing so far. Most of the time it's url problem or backslashes etc. Not this time though

```
<div id="est"></div>

#est {
    margin-left:55px;
    margin-top:55px;
    background-image: url(http://blabla.com/wp-content/themes/blankslate.3.3/blankslate/images/est.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

I've been trying everything. Local url/full url, quotation marks (single and double), bacground-imgage:/background. No luck...
Html file reads styles sheet.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div has no height or width... add both and you will see it. ;)

Alternetively add content to your div.

Comment: added background-size:165px 16px; still no go

Comment: with `#est {width:165px;height:16px;...}` it is working. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your background image link gives a 404 error. You need to put in a proper link!